# Nginx ingress: exception rule for one child path

Tags: nginx-ingress

I have to expose `/app` without auth but everything under `/app/v2` has to use basic auth
For this sake I created two set of Ingress rules:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ing-auth
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: test.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /app
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: app-svc1
              port:
                number: 80

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ing-auth
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.org/basic-auth-secret: "basic-auth-nginx"
    nginx.org/basic-auth-realm: "Authentication Required"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: test.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /app/v2
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: app-svc1
              port:
                number: 80
```

But it doesn't work, `http://test.com/app/v2` available without auth
If I disable rule for path `/app` auth for `http://test.com/app/v2` becomes required but `http://test.com/app/` stops working (obviously)
The question is how to build Ingress rules so `/app/v2` is exception from `/app` rules?